# Python merge overlapping paths

Tags: python, string, merge

I am trying to merge 2 overlapping paths in the following way:

wd= /home/user/project1/scripts/test1

path=~/project1/task1/file.txt

output= /home/user/project1/task1/file.txt

I have tried what suggested in similar posts  but I don't get my desired output:

```
wd='/home/user/project1/scripts/test1'

path='~/project1/task1/file.txt'

print(os.path.join(wd, path))
```

Comment: This seems arbitrary. First you need to come up with an algorithm on how you want to merge the paths. For example. Resolve the ~ then take the home directory of var2 and substitute that into var1. then take the first part of var1 and the last part of var2. Currently the info available in this question there is no way to make an algorithm that works for all given paths.

Comment: split `wd` by `project1`, get the 0th element and append `path` to that element?

Comment: Are you looking for os.expanduser?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using this solution:

```py
import os
wd = '/home/user/project1/scripts/test1'
path = '~/project1/task1/file.txt'
output = wd+'/'+os.path.basename(path)
print(output)
```

Comment: Maybe use `os.path.join()` for `output`.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this?

```
import os
wd= '/home/user/project1/scripts/test1'
path='~/project1/task1/file.txt'

path = path.replace('~','/home/user')
print(path)
```

It outputs "/home/user/project1/task1/file.txt"

Comment: you shouldn't use `str.replace` for the `~`. a much better solution would be to use `os.expanduser`.